# While loop doesn't stop when space is encountered

Tags: python, while-loop

I have this:

```
subString = ""                      
for i in range(0,len(string)):
    while string[i].isspace() != True:  # The important part.
        subString += string[i]

print subString
```

I'm trying to write a section of code that prints a sub-string that contains all of the characters of another string up to but not including the first white-space character. I figured that the condition I put on the `while` loop would do it, but when I run the program, when it gets to that part, it never exits the loop. What's wrong?

Comment: Try tracing the program through in your head. What would you expect it to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never change the variable `i` in the while loop, so the value of the expression `string[i].isspace()` never changes. This leads to an infinite loop.

Comment: Why doesn't the for loop cause the value of i to change?

Comment: A while loop just checks the condition. It doesn't alter the value of any variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
subString = ""                      
for c in string:
    if c.isspace():
        break
    subString += c

print subString
```